# How do i go back to windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

I have accidently installed ubuntu on my windows 8 64bit partition. I have only had one partition. Now i cannot go back. Can  you help me with a solution to go back to my windows 8?

Comment: But most of your data is lost. Everything not overwritten by the few GB of data that encompasses a standard Ubuntu-Installation might still be recoverable by professional tools.

Answer (score 2):

Your harddrive has been erased.  You'll need to reinstall Windows. There is probably a license key sticker underneath your laptop(or somewhere on the machine) for which you can download Windows again.  Check the documentation that came with the machine, or Google the model number for the documentation.

Comment: The activation key is stored in the motherboard. So it activates automatically.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a laptop, it is very likely that there is a recovery partition. Try to google "Laptop model recovery".

It is likely that you have overwritten the windows installation, and it is probably hard to get that exact setup back.